# Find out Leakage issues in Looper or HandlerThread

Tags: android, android-handler, android-looper

I have used some Handlers like

```
           new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Messages.onAcknowledgeReceived();                                       

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
            });
```

It executes in each 15 seconds and after sometimes it started throwing some warnings like

```
 The Looper class instance count has over a limit(100). There should be some leakage of Looper or HandlerThread.
 12-16 12:16:11.357: E/Looper(4647): Looper class instance count = 221
 12-16 12:16:11.357: E/Looper(4647): Current Thread Name: IntentService[AppService]
 12-16 12:16:12.316: E/Looper(4647): WARNING: The Looper class instance count has over a   limit(100). There should be some leakage of Looper or HandlerThread.
 12-16 12:16:12.318: E/Looper(4647): Looper class instance count = 222
 12-16 12:16:12.318: E/Looper(4647): Current Thread Name: IntentService[GCMIntentService-419284807656-203]
```

Is there any wrong in my programming approach ? I still not understand where is the leakage in this bit of code.

Comment: what is `Messages` ? It's not an android class.. can you show the implementation of `Messages.onAcknowledgeReceived();`?

Comment: I've got the same issue on Kitkat